# Deleting and changing google appengine endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created a small project in Google apengine and like it apart from one thing: It seems virtually impossible to delete or change an endpoint, once it has been made. The API often stays the same, regardless of code changes in the java endpoint classes. I tried to delete the complete API, but that is not possible either. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

## RE: Deletion

it's not currently supported, but we're working on it.

## RE: API Changes

The [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/) web app aggressively caches, so you'll need to clear your cache or force a refresh when you update your API server side to see the changes in the client.

Comment: The doc's from the trusted tester program did state that deletion was available since 1.7.5. But I haven't found a way to do it ;-)

Comment: Well, I read it to mean fixed via the Docs here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sloZ36iSmq16piwaZxaq1ssMsUE0Z-jdL721ky7sVKM/edit for the known issue list for 1.7.5.

Comment: It is fixed but not supported fully. We'll have documentation for this once fully ready; I'll try to remember to update this answer at that time.